# What is the difference between "stock up" and "store up"?

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

Could you please help me out by explaining the subtle sense of these phrasal verbs?

> In one experiment over several weeks, volunteers were asked either to
> **stock up** on snacks (chocolate, fruit and crisps) at the start or
> select a snack each week.

Why using "store up" instead would be a mistake?

Comment: And just to clarify, we say **stock up on X** but **store up X**  (not "store up **on** X").

Answer (score 2):

**stock up on snacks** is more colloquial than **store up snacks**.

(In the UK we say "stock up", "stock up on" and "store up", but not "store up on.")

Perhaps *stocking up on snacks* suggests we *might* eat them, or start eating them, this evening. And perhaps *storing up snacks* suggests they are meant to last for quite a long time.

That's the *short* answer! It may be all you need. But...

The verbs *to stock* and *to store* have somewhat different meanings.

When you stock something you have it available to sell.
When you store something you keep or accumulate it for future use.

These definitions are from Lexico ([stock up](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stock)), ([store up](https://www.lexico.com/definition/store)) and from Macmillan ([stock up](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stock-up)), ([store up](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/store-up)) and you might find it helpful to visit them and read all the examples: Lexico has many.

So *stock* and *store* are subtly different. But *store up* and *stock up* can be **very** different. Some dictionaries say only *store up* is a phrasal verb: others say they both are.

**[stock up](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stock)** is intransitive. The addition of "up" doesn't introduce any complexity and its meaning can be easily deduced. It means:

*amass supplies of something, typically for a particular occasion or purpose.*
Example: *‘Long lines quickly formed at grocery stores and gas stations, as worried residents stocked up on supplies.’*

**[store up](https://www.lexico.com/definition/store)** is transitive. It can mean:

*to keep a lot of something so that you can use it later*
Example: *'Many animals store up food for the winter.'*

This seems to be used only with uncountable nouns: food, energy, heat etc.

Or

*to remember something, especially so that you can tell or ask someone later*
Example: *'I had stored up a few questions to ask her about the job.'*

Or

*Create problems for the future by failing to address a particular situation adequately at the time.*
Example: ‘*What's happening today is storing up major problems for the future.*’

Answer (score -1):

Stock up and store up, can be used interchangeably.

Stock up tends to be used for "discrete units" like bricks, candy, etc.

Store up is more used for "fluid" or "continuous" units, like energy or goodwill.

Both are interchangeable, but have a different "feel" to it.

Candy:

- I stocked up on candy.
- I stored up on candy.

Energy:

- I stocked up on energy. (doesn't "feel" right, but it works)
- I stored up on energy.